# jobsend sends no data even though return code is 1?

Tags: vimscript, neovim, job-control

So I am trying to send some json text to a python script with jobsend in neovim like this:

```
let l:json_msg = json_encode(a:msg)
call jobsend(s:vimwatcher_job, l:json_msg)
```

If i `echo l:json_msg` I can see that the l:json_msg is a properly encoded string yet my program receives nothing from stdin at all.

If I run `echo jobsend(s:vimwatcher_job, l:json_msg)` I can see that the return code is 1 so it seems to succeed.

It works fine however in normal vim like this (without the encoding and setting the in_mode on job_start to "json")

```
call ch_sendexpr(s:vimwatcher_job, a:msg)
```

Any idea what could go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing newlines, I assumed that jobsend appended newlines to each message since ch_sendexpr did but that was not the case.

Reading the documentation and stubling upon an example made me find the solution. When using ch_sendraw in normal vim I would also need newlines, so it all makes sense.